# Using logrotate recipe in chef - no rotated logs created

Tags: chef-infra, logrotate, log-rotation

I am trying to use the chef logrotate recipe.

```
include_recipe "logrotate"
logrotate_app "kafka-logs" do
  cookbook "logrotate"
  path "/tmp/kafka.log"
  frequency "daily"
  size "1k"
  rotate 10
  create "0644 root root"
end
```

I am trying to rotate given a size. I used 1K test.  Yet..when I ingest data..I see no rotation.  where are the logs?  there is no /tmp/kafka.1.log etc..

Should I not see the rotated logs in /tmp dir?

Answer (score 4):

Logrotate is triggered via a cronjob, so check the frequency of your cronjob to verify that the rotation process is actually being triggered by a timer.